# Bayesian statistic in model comparison

Tags: bayesian, model-selection, multiple-comparisons, model, biostatistics

I am trying to use the Bayesian statistic in model comparison.
Let's say I have 4 different pharmacokinetic models which I use to fit breast MRI data. Each of this model M gives me a certain number of parameters:

1. M1: K12 and K21 for the first one (2 params)
2. M2: K12 K21 and v for the second one (3 params)
3. M3: k12 k21 v and t for the third one (4 params)
4. M4: s1 s2 s3 v1 v2 v3 k1 k2 k3 g for the fourth one (9 params)

Now I would like to make a model comparison with the Bayesian statistics.
I know I have, for the first two:

P(M1|D) / P(M2|D) = P(D1|M1) / P(D2|M2) * P(M1)/P(M2)

I know that the Bayes factor is proportional to the log of the likelihood but:

1. Is it simply the residual sum of squares over the number of data points?
2. what is the prior probability of each model?

Thank you.
I really appreciate any help.

Comment: "the Bayes factor is proportional to the log of the likelihood": this is incorrect.

Comment: let's say
ln BF ~ ln L - k^2/2
where L is the likelihood and k is the significance of the measurements